# C# WPF XAML A first chance exception of type ... occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to design an application I am working on and I'm working on the XAML.  There is a DockPanel and inside it is a StackPanel docked to the left and another to the right.  I keep getting the error `A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll`.  The error is happening on the line where the ImageBrush tag is.  Why is this happening?

Here is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="730" Width="1220">
    <DockPanel>
        <Border BorderBrush="#FF5AD8E5" BorderThickness="0,0,3,0">
            <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="208">
                <StackPanel.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/assets/img/nav_primary.png"></ImageBrush>
                </StackPanel.Background>            
                <Label Content="Welcome, Scott!" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="16" Padding="5,15,15,5" OpacityMask="Black" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="Auto">

        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: guessing that your ImageSource isn't valid, try removing the stackpanel's background and see if that fixes it. If so, then that is your problem.

Comment: Well, yes, that is the problem.  The question is, how do I fix it without getting rid of the ImaegBrush?

Comment: Make sure that there is a folder named `assets` in your Visual Studio Project, with a subfolder named `img`, containing the image file `nav_primary.png`. And that the file's Build Action is set to Resource.